# Data from c# application into Ms Access transferring incorrectly

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

```
...
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace accessloginapp
{
    public partial class Ramen : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

        public Ramen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString =
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\...\Users.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try{
                connection.Open();

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText =
                    "insert into userdata (Username,[Password]) values('" +
                    txt_Username + "','" + txt_Password + "')";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Users added and saved");
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if I do not understand much, I'm fairly to new to this. When I save data such as username and password in my application, the data is inserted as what I input but with added text, Example: I would send the username `"Mark"` to be inserted, but when I go to look at my database, it is put in as `"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Mark"`. How can I change this to only inserting the Username I Input?

Comment: you are passing an Object for each (the textbox) rather than the text which they contain.  But that is the least of your problems.  Learn about SQL parameters and hasing passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Text` property of textbox control, to fetch the actual text stored:-

```
 command.CommandText = "insert into userdata (Username,[Password]) 
           values('" + txt_Username.Text + "','" + txt_Password.Text + "')";
```

Apart from this please note your query is open for [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

So, you should use Parameterized query something like this:-

```
command.CommandText = "insert into userdata (Username,[Password]) 
               values(?,?)";
command.Parameters.Add("?",OleDbType.VarChar,20).Value = txt_Username.Text;
```

and similarly add parameter for `@Password`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I feel stupid forgetting .Text. I'm new to this, I'll look into protecting against an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Note that with OleDB parameters are positional: `INSERT INTO userdata (Username,[Password]) VALUES (?, ?)`. Then add the params like this: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txt_Username.Text);  
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txt_Password.Text);`